# SQLAlchemy UUID has no sa_instance_state as part of relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-dataclasses

I have Task dataclass where a Task can depend on other Tasks:

```
@dataclass
class Task:
    id: UUID
    description: str
    depends_on: list[UUID]
```

Using the code below (and some imports and boilerplate) I can create a task and add it to a database when depends_on is the empty list. So UUID serialization works. However, when I try to add a task that depends on another, I get an error `'UUID' object has not attribute _sa_instance'`

```
table_task = Table(
    'tbl_task',
    mapper_registry.metadata,
    Column('id', Uuid(as_uuid=True, native_uuid=False), primary_key=True),
    Column('description', String))

table_task_association = Table(
    'tbl_task_association',
    mapper_registry.metadata,
    Column('parent_task_id', Uuid(as_uuid=True, native_uuid=False), ForeignKey('tbl_task.id'), primary_key=True),
    Column('depends_on_id', Uuid(as_uuid=True, native_uuid=False), primary_key=True))

mapper_registry.map_imperatively(
    Task,
    table_task,
    properties={
        "depends_on": relationship(
            Task,
            secondary=table_task_association,
            primaryjoin=table_task_association.c.parent_task_id == table_task.c.id,
            secondaryjoin=table_task_association.c.depends_on_id == table_task.c.id)
    }
)

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')
mapper_registry.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

t = Task(uuid4(),'task1',[])
t2 = Task(uuid4(), 'task2',[t.id])

session = create_session(bind=engine)
session.add(t)
session.add(t2)  # This is the line that causes the error.
session.commit()
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here?